# Retrieve string from custom object based on title defined in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

I need to retrieve content from a field in a custom object based on the "title" of the record. While the code below works, it has obviously been told specifically to return the record with the title 'Topics'. What I need to be able to do is define this from the Visualforce code, something like the following

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!pkbCon.PKBContentByName['Topics']}"/>
//Or this
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!pkbCon.PKBContentByName.Topics}"/>
```

I am very new to SF dev, and have been using code written by others to get this working so far. I appreciate your input!

**Apex Class**

```
public Map<String, PKB_Content__c > mapPKBContent {get;set;}
public pkb_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
  mapPKBContent = DLUtility.getPKBContentMap();
}
public static String getPKBContentByName() {
  Map<String, PKB_Content__c > mapPKBContent = DLUtility.getPKBContentMap();
  return mapPKBContent.get('Topics').Content__c;
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!pkbCon.PKBContentByName}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to have several titles like 'Topic' hard coded in the page, then `mapPKBContent` needs to be exposed in the controller through a `getMapPKBContent` method or this style of getter:

```
public Map<String, PKB_Content__c> mapPKBContent {
    get {
        return DLUtility.getPKBContentMap();
    }
}
```

(The code posted in your question doesn't initialise the `mapPKBContent` field.)

Then as gsbasso shows, you can output fields from the `PKB_Content__c` object for a particular title like this:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!mapPKBContent['Topics'].Content__c}"/>
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!mapPKBContent['OtherTitle'].OtherField__c}"/>
```

Comment: Keith, I really appreciate your detail here. My apologies it looks like I left out my lines that initializes mapPKBContent. I've added that code into my original question at this time. Any further instruction would be really appreciated!

Comment: I actually had it working, just forgot to set public permissions on my object :) Really appreciate the help and specificity, Keith!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Apex class is the controller you should basically be able to do something like:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!mapPKBContent['Topics'].Content__c}"/>
```

You'll need to ensure the map object is initialized, for example in the controller constructor or through lazy initialization within the map property getter.

Comment: The key is that gsbasso is referring to the field on the object in the outputText, while TheElks is just referring to the object itself (which doesn't have a string value inherently).